# Spring Boot - Custom JSON Serialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I generally use mixins to perform custom serialization and deserialization when using Jackson Library. My RestController in Spring Boot app has methods similar to one listed below. I guess Spring Boot uses Jackson to serialize the VerifyAccountResponse into string. However this converts my calendar / date objects into a long value when they are converted to String. I am able to convert them into appropriate format by using custom serializer. However I am having to change the return type into an object after serialization. Is there a way to retain the same signature and add custom serializer to default serialization performed by Spring Boot.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="verifyAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<VerifyAccountResponse> verifyAccount(@RequestBody VerifyAccountRequest request) {

    VerifyAccountResponse response = service.verifyAccount(request);

    return new ResponseEntity<VerifyAccountResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

EDIT:

```
Updated the below based on the answers , but mixin doesn't seem to take effect -

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

    builder.mixIn(ConnectStatus.class, com.datacast.service.util.DateFormatSerializerMixin.class);

    return builder;
}
```

EDIT 2:

I created a simple spring boot project to  test this out and this works fine. But when I use this approach in my larger project , the date conversion is not happening. Could there be anything overriding Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder ?

Comment: Can you add an example of current serialization and desire? You can always annotate your bean to use a custom serialization and Spring-Boot will use it.

Comment: @jbarrueta my classes are in a jar file and I cannot add annotations on them. I'm using Jackson mixins for serialization

Comment: This might help you: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: @PunterVicky - the default serialization is Jersey via Jackson, so anything that is Jersey via Jackson is applicable and exactly the same. The *answers* are just links to the documenatation **you have not read yourself** and just link only answers with some minimal explination of what the links represent and thus very low quality.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize the Jackson serializer in a spring boot application in a lot of ways. Please consider checking the documentation regarding jackson [in the spring boot reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper).

You can configure a custom serializer by using **Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder**.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html#serializerByType-java.lang.Class-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer-

Comment: Thanks @Lakatos. I updated the mixins but still doesn't take effect. I have updated the code in my original post.

Comment: I implemented this in a separate program and this works great. However when I used it in my app , it didn't return the formatted date. I am extending classes from few jars which are using EnableMvc annotation. I am suspecting this causing serialization from being performed.

Answer (score 6):

You can customize date format (as I understand it's the main reason of your post) by setting property

```
spring.jackson.date-format= 
# Date format string or a fully-qualified date format class name.
For instance `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.
```

Comment: Thanks @dimuha. But I have multiple date fields each having different format.