# Serialize LocalDate to JSON Date

Tags: json, date, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot 2.1.1. I migrated from Date to LocalDate wherever possible. My REST endpoints correctly serialize these dates in the following form

```
2017-01-01
```

Nevertheless, I would like to format local dates in a JavaScript format:

```
2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z
```

How can I achieve this globally in my SpringBoot configuration without having to annotate each entity with a CustomSerializer?

The reason behind my question is, that Angular will not automatically parse non Standard JavaScript dates, so I would have to parse each date manually.

Comment: maybe try LocalDateTime ;-) cause LocalDate contains only Year, Month and Day https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: That would work but I don't need it. I would like to put only 0 for hours, minutesn and so on there.

Comment: so why do you not converting the LocalDate into a LocalDateTime before returing it? cause angular expects a datetime https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe otherwise maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627170/spring-boot-custom-json-serialization